# Set uploaded tag value as service account name in google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I have an application that dumps files to google drive using a service account , once the files are uploaded and if I check the Activity tab in google drive it shows "**Unknown** uploaded 12 items"(as shown in picture). Now we have a business requirement that this **Unknown** should be replaced with name of service-account using which files were uploaded.I have been searching the drive-api documentation for quite long but didn't found anything.I am using the drive v3 api and the backend application is written in java.
My question is, is there any way to do this ? Thanks in anticipation.

[image]

Comment: A workaround for this could be to grant the service account domain-wide authority, and upload the files with the service account impersonating this regular account. This way, you would not get `Unknown`, but the name of this regular account on the Activity tab. Do you think that would be appropriate for you? If that's the case, I'd consider posting an answer explaining this in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You cant change the name of the service account user you dont have any control over that.

The only thing i can think of is when you update the file to set the display name of the lastModifyingUser.displayName.  It appears to be writable but i have never tried actually sending it before.

[File resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource)

## Gsuite

If this is a gsutie account you could set up domain-wide deligation to a user on the domain and have that user do the uploading.  The name will then appear corect.

Comment: I tried writing to lastModifyingUser and got a fieldNotWritable error unfortunately.